# Wide equation - how to avoid the equation number on next line?

Tags: equations, matrices

I have an equation with a large matrix that I want numbered as an equation. I use the code shown underneath:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{equation}
    Y_{12} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{x'_{d1}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d3}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d4}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d5}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d6}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d7}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d8}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d9}} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d10}} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This code works for smaller matrices. But with a large matrix the width of the equation seems to be wider than the `\textwidth`, as the equation numbering goes on the line below the matrix. How can I get the equation number at the same line as the equation?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) latex moves the eq number for a reason, if you fill theer is enough room for it, please provide us a fully compilable example that we can copy and test without having to add any code.  (here for example we need to a a preamble for this to work

Comment: You could try changing `\arraycolsep`  to a smaller value,   say 4 pt.

Comment: @daleif (1) Thank you, (2) I edited the code, I hope this is okay. (3) I also have another matrix that is so large that it goes outside the actual page. I would like to center it (regardless of whether the equation number is on the same line or not). Do you know how I do that?

Answer (score 2):

What are all those zeros good for, why not just write that this is a diagonal matrix with these entries:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    Y_{12} = -\diag\Bigl( & \frac{1}{x'_{d1}}, \frac{1}{x'_{d2}},
    \frac{1}{x'_{d3}}, \frac{1}{x'_{d4}}, \frac{1}{x'_{d5}},
    \frac{1}{x'_{d6}},\frac{1}{x'_{d7}}, \frac{1}{x'_{d8}}, \frac{1}{x'_{d9}},
    \frac{1}{x'_{d10}} \Bigr)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For other matrix constructions one can break them up into smaller pieces, and write something like: To ease notation we first define ...

It is just a matter of not being locked into convention

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of `\arraycolsep` or reduce the size of the font with the `\medmath` command from `nccmath`(about 80 % of `displaystyle`). You also can load `geometry` to have more sensible margins, if you don't use margin notes.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{.3pt}
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

     \begin{document}

     \begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
        Y_{12} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -\frac{1}{x'_{d1}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d3}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d4}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d5}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d6}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d7}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d8}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d9}} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d10}} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

 \begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
        Y_{12} =
        \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
        -\frac{1}{x'_{d1}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d3}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d4}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d5}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d6}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d7}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d8}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d9}} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x'_{d10}} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]